# "Null-Safe" collection-language

Tags: collections, syntax, type-safety

**Disclaimer: Please edit this question if you have a better title or tags**

There are languages [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) that provide null-safety at compile-time. The compiler will throw syntax-errors if a variable is read before it was initialised.

- Is there a language, that can ensure at compile-time that a collection will contain a certain value (identified by an integer index or an arbitrary id) before that value is accessed within the collection?
- Is there a formal language dealing with this?

**Example 1**

```kotlin
val list = ArrayList<String>()

val obj: String = list.get(0) // --> syntax error (x is empty at this point)
```

**Example 2**

```kotlin
val map = HashMap<String, String>()    
map.put("key1", "test")

val obj: String = map.get("key2")  // --> syntax error (Key2 is not in the map)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type

Comment: Are you asking for something like "the type of all collections in which the fifth element has the value 8"? If so, then, as Ryan mentions, check out dependent types. If you need more than that, can you clarify the question?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what I'm looking for. I'ved added two examples.